# Passar Token pelo header a cada requisição AngularJS (Authorization )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, token, authorization

Tenho o arquivo interface-factory.js que é minha fabrica

```
app.factory('interfaceAPI', function ($http) {

var _getInterface = function () {
    return $http.get("/api/interfaceapi/getall");
};

var _postInterface = function (objeto) {
    return $http.post("/api/interfaceapi/post", objeto);
};

var _deleteInterface = function (Id) {
    return $http.delete("/api/interfaceapi/delete/" + Id);
};


return {
    getInterface: _getInterface,
    postInterface: _postInterface,
    deleteInterface: _deleteInterface
};
```

});

o token já esta sendo gerado e sendo guardado do localStorage, gostaria de saber como passar o token no header de cada requisição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o problema é você:

```
var myToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = myToken.token_type + ' ' + myToken.access_token;
```

basta voce colocar o codigo acima do:

```
var _getInterface = function () {

    return $http.get("/api/interfaceapi/getall");
};

var _postInterface = function (objeto) {
    return $http.post("/api/interfaceapi/post", objeto);
};

var _deleteInterface = function (Id) {
    return $http.delete("/api/interfaceapi/delete/" + Id);
};


return {
    getInterface: _getInterface,
    postInterface: _postInterface,
    deleteInterface: _deleteInterface
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Para setar o cabeçalho `authorization` basta fazer o seguinte:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + token;
```

Se for o caso, basta trocar o 'Basic' por 'Bearer' ou deixar apenas o token, dependendo do método de autenticação que esteja usando.

**EDIT:**

O cabeçalho deve ser setado antes da requisição ser enviada. Por exemplo:

```
var _getInterface = function () {
    var myToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = myToken.token_type + myToken.access_token;
    return $http.get("/api/interfaceapi/getall");
};
```

Assumindo que `myToken.token_type` é o tipo do token e o `myToken.access_token` é o token em si.

Comment: var myToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = myToken.token_type + myToken.access_token;

Desta forma?

Comment: @JeffersonSouza editei a resposta de acordo com o código que vc informou. Espero que resolva o seu problema!

Comment: deste modo nao funcionou.

Comment: Apareceu algum erro no console ou simplesmente não setou o cabeçalho?

Comment: nao setou o cabeçalho

Comment: return $http.get("/api/interfaceapi/getall"), config; ai consigo entrar na pagina que eu quero, mas sei que não é o correto. config é minha variavel onde recebe o tipo do token e o token

Comment: dei um console.log para ver se os valores estão sendo pegados, e estão

Comment: Por desencargo de consciência, faça um teste usando: `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = ...`

Comment: juntamente com o codigo que voce enviou?

Comment: Sim. No caso, substituir a terceira linha do exemplo que citei `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = myToken.token_type + myToken.access_token;` por `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = myToken.token_type + myToken.access_token;`